# CodeIgniter Auto Loading form_validation causes Error with Model files

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am using CodeIgniters form_validation library to validate a form in my app. Library loaded here:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','form_validation');
```

Ever since including the library I cannot load any models in the app. I get the following error in my browser. The form is a registration form for users to sign up to the site. The form gets validated perfectly.

```
 A PHP Error was encountered

 Severity: Notice

 Message: Undefined property: register_model::$load

 Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php

 Line Number: 147
```

Here is my function that tries to load the model:

```
  public function validateRegForm(){
    $this->load->model('register_model');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm-password', 'Confirm Password', 'required|matches[password]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
     $data['title'] = 'Sign Up';

     $this->load->view('template/header', $data);
     $this->load->view('template/navigation');
     $this->load->view('register_view');
     $this->load->view('template/footer');
    } else {

      $data = array(
        'firstName' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
        'lastName' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
        'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'password'=> $this->input->post('password')
      );

      $this->register_model->insertUsers($data);
    }
}
```

Register model file:

```
 <?php
 class register_model extends CI_Controller {

 //Insert a new user to users table when registration form submits
   function insertUser(){

     $query = $this->db->query();

   }

}

?>
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Is that the entire `register_model` file?

Comment: @DFriend yep that's the entire file, all I want to do is insert the data from the form into the database. I will insert the query into the query function later.

Comment: When exactly does the error message appear? When you load the page? When you submit the form?

Comment: @DFriend when the form passes all validation and submits

Comment: What happens if you remove (or comment out) `$this->register_model->insertUsers($data);` from `validateRegForm`? Still get the error?

Comment: Just to be certain: You click the submit button on the form and then the error appears?

Comment: @DFriend still get the error but if i remove  $this->load->model('register_model');  no error.

Comment: what version of codeigniter are you using?

Comment: @DFriend version 3.1.0, gorans93 answer below worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove form validation library from autoload, and load it inside of controller.

```
  public function __CONSTRUCT(){
    parent::_CONSTRUCT();
    $this->load->model('register_model');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation'); // load it from controller like this 
  }


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm-password', 'Confirm Password', 'required|matches[password]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
     $data['title'] = 'Sign Up';

     $this->load->view('template/header', $data);
     $this->load->view('template/navigation');
     $this->load->view('register_view');
     $this->load->view('template/footer');
    } else {

      $data = array(
        'firstName' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
        'lastName' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
        'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'password'=> $this->input->post('password')
      );

      $this->register_model->insertUsers($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
class register_model extends CI_Controller {
```

and make the initial letter of the class name upper case.

```
class Register_model extends CI_Controller {
```

In addition, the file name must begin with an upper case letter. It should be named Register_model.php